# i'm trying to insert to the data base but i have an error called overflow

Tags: c#, mysql

this is the code

```
public static void ChangeTable(string strSql, string FileName) 
{ 
    OleDbConnection c = MakeConnection(FileName); 
    OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand(); 
    comm.CommandText = strSql; 
    comm.Connection = c; 
    comm.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
    c.Close(); 
}
```

---

```
strSql = "Insert into h3rot(name,lastname,tlfon,nyad,email,brodcuts)" + 
         " VALUES(
         '
         " + 
         TextBox1.Text + 
         "','" + 
         TextBox2.Text + 
         "'," + 
         phone + 
         "," + 
         pel + 
         ",'" + 
         TextBox5.Text + 
         "','" + 
         DropDownList1.Text + "
         ')";
```

Comment: What have you tired? does the string evaluate to correct sql.  do you need to scrub the text from the text boxes?

Comment: please point your error specificly, at which part you get that error?

Comment: i called this function   public static void ChangeTable(string strSql, string FileName)
    {
        OleDbConnection c = MakeConnection(FileName);
        OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand();
        comm.CommandText = strSql;
        comm.Connection = c;
        comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        c.Close();
    }   from class named Dbase the error overflow is on comm.ExecuteNonQuery()

Comment: what is the schema definition for that h3rot table?

Answer (score 3):

1) your code is **SCREAMING** out "sql injection" so you should **REALLY** be doing something to sanitize all of those textboxes.  And you should at least be using parameter markers instead of just appending strings together.

2) you've probably exceeded the size of one of the columns in your database.  without more information about what was in the textboxes or the schema of the database, there's not much else to say.

Comment: @sentya: Database column allows 50 characters. You insert a string that contains 51 characters into that column. Your string has overflowed the space available, and you get an error.

Comment: @sentya 2) explains what overflow means for this situation.

Comment: It means bigger then allowed. Its used whenever the data is in some way of greater magnitude then the design, and your text boxes are a problem since a user could put text in there that would do bad things.

Comment: is this the same error "Number of query values ​​and destination fields is not identical" ???

Comment: i checked that all the column names are exist in my database

Comment: "number of query values ​​and destination fields is not identical" means that you have N columns listed in the insert statement, but N+M or N-M values listed in the VALUES section of the insert statement.

Comment: sorry my bad missed the number word

Answer (score 0):

try `DropDownList1.SelectedValue`

Comment: @sentya yeah, you better start from checking your database and allowed varchar size, compare it with `DropDownList1.SelectedValue`

Comment: i shecked it hundred times i even deleted all the codes and rewrote it

Comment: i really neeeed an answer my exam is tomorrow

Comment: when i insert Manually into the database the column [nyad] can inclode max length 5 characters why is that ??????

Comment: because the columns is defined as being 5 characters long?  this is why we've been asking for schema details...

Comment: @sentya when designing your database table h3rot you design that `nyad` column to take maximum 5 characters that's the whole problem, give it a greater number. design your table with right clicking it is easy.

Comment: actually i didn't design this database it's for my friend she asked me to help her ... thank u all for your help

Comment: @sentya and try to relax a little, that exam is not the end of the world.

Comment: @sentya well, you tagged mysql in your question, you can design it with mysql too.And if maximum 5 character is what it has to be you gotta send smaller values in the query. i dont really see any other choice.

Comment: @sentya no problem dark guy, gl with your exam

Comment: thank u and  I really appreciate your concern.. hh how did u knew im a brunette girl !!